# Need a migration when changing from nullbooleanfield to booleanfield?

Tags: django, database, django-models, database-migration, django-migrations

I'm using an older version of django and I'm trying to upgrade to the latest version of django.
While proceeding, I encountered the following error.

```sh
(fields.E903) NullBooleanField is removed except for support in historical migrations.
        HINT: Use BooleanField(null=True) instead.
```

Do I need to migrate when changing `models.NullBooleanField()` to `models.BooleanField(null=True)`?
The table has many columns. Migration is a big burden. Is there any other way to bypass that issue?
The DB is using Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Using NullBooleanField is now [discouraged](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield).
but you can used `BooleanField` and You can restore the previous behavior by setting `blank=True.`

note :In older versions, this field has blank=True implicitly